# callback vs direct calling function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await, callback, ssh2

Original question is what difference is there if i call a function without callback or with callback

i am using ssh2 library to list directory on remote sftp server for that there is a function "readdir"

if i call readdir as below  it works all perfect

```
readdir(path, (err, list)=>{
         console.log(list); //list have all data as it should be
}
```

but if i call function like this (to use it normally in async function)

```
list= readdir(path);
```

above code return error from ssh2 dependency ssh2-streams

error is

```
cb is not a function
cb(undefined, stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source at https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/blob/master/lib/protocol/SFTP.js, you will see that this function is describe as a callback function.
You need to put the parameters as in the first case if you don't want to raise an error.